# Remove Interface Members from Implementation when Interface Changes

Tags: c#, interface, interface-implementation

### Situation:

I implement an interface implicit and remove a property on the interface (later).
There is no warning that this property should be removed on the implementation class.

I know I could implement the interface explicitly, but I would try to go around that.

---

EDIT: (added a question)

How can I be notified/warned/... that I maybe no longer need the member in the implementing class?

Comment: So what is the question here?

Comment: There's nothing built in to do that. You may be able to add a new, incompatible, property to the interface using the same name, then use the compiler errors to track down the offending code (then remove the new property)

Comment: It is impossible to detect, as the class is still valid, regardless if the given property respects an interface or not. Explicit interface implementation will give you the compile-time error you seek, and if you need implicit exposure of the property/method, you can always have both implicit and explicit implementations. The latter is a manner to just have the indication the interface no longer supports a given method/property, so you can make "informed decision" while working with the implementing types

Comment: Resharper can detect some dead code (solution wide analysis, but it is very slow) and add little icons showing that the property satisfies an interface.

Comment: Visual Studio adds the interface-members in a #region... so it is obviously (at least for human) that it shouldn't be there anymore... is there a code-analysis-tool ore similar that could tell me that?

Comment: It's easy to identify when a class claims to implement an interface but has missing members. But note that you'll get no such warnings if you add an interface to a class that *happens* to already have compatible members - either just because it makes sense for that class to have them or because it also implements another interface that requires the same members.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way the compiler can give you such a warning in C#. It would somehow need to have knowledge of past versions of the interface to know what method/property was removed and therefore identify possible candidates for removal.

And answering your commentary, you can not make the compiler / refactoring tool decide if any given method is a candidate simply based on the `#region` its defined in. There is absolutetly nothing that enforces any given method to be defined in any given `region`, its just visual sugar so refactoring based on regions would be completely unsafe.

Sometimes verbose languages do have advantages, and in this case VB with the `implements` keyword would make this a compile time error. In C#, you have to use explicitly implemented interfaces which is not a bad option at all. Read [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/392516/Why-I-use-explicit-interface-implementation-as-a-d) for more details.

Comment: Maybe I am getting convinced to use explicit more often in future... but what about existing code? Even Resharper cannot make implicit --> explicit completely automated (as far as I could find out)

Comment: @joerg Well refactoring implicit to explicit is a major breaking change so I'm not sure that is an option you'd want to take with existing code.

Comment: You are right... it's just very annoying to often find this no-longer-needed-properties in my implementations... ;)